# 3d analog of Koch snowflake

Tags: 3d, fractals

By analogy with 2d Koch snowflake is there a 3d solid, like a Koch "snowball"?

The solid is made by indefinitely & centrally *adding one-third sided regular tetrahedrons* on each of its starting one unit 4 equilateral triangle faces resulting in  infinite surface area enclosing finite volume.

What may be the snowball volume?

[image]

Comment: Because the first stage is a _stella octangula_, two tetrahedrons inscribed in a cube, it should be reasonably plausible that the limit analogous to a Koch snowflake (the closure of the countable union) is "the circumscribed cube" around the original tetrahedron.

Comment: I did not take the infinite series summation of one-third tetras to its finish.

Comment: The diagram helps; my previous comment is irrelevant. Briefly, yes (the closure of) the countable union does exist, and is a finite-volume set that appears to have infinite surface area (at each stage the area of the finite union is multiplied by $11/9$).